# Unbinding key events in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template which has a key event

```
Template.layout.events({
  'keyup': function (e, template) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do some stuff here, isn't important for question
      Router.go('Users.profile', { _id: id });
    }
  }
});
```

However, when I change pages, it seems the event is still bound to the enter button.

I imagine the first step is to use an `onDestroyed` callback on my template.

```
Template.layout.onDestroyed(function () {
  // ???
});
```

How would you unbind key events on page change in meteor?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Meteor natively supports removing events added via `Template.name.events`. There are a few resolutions I can think of in this case:

1. Handle the special case inside the Event handler, which means coupling the handler with the rest of the application logic. This may or may not suit your needs.
2. Attaching a (namespaced) event handler `.onRendered` using jQuery and then removing it explicitly `.onDestroyed`.
3. Bind the `keyup` event more tightly to the element in focus. If that element is removed from the DOM, the handler will also be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are destroyed automatically when the template is destroyed. But, with a name like `layout`, I'm guessing that template exists on multiple routes. If this is the case, add a `console.log` to `onDestroyed()` and see if it even gets destroyed when you want it to. To fix this, attach the `keyup` listener on a more specific template, for instance if you have this

```
<template name="layout">
  {{>settingsMenu}}
</template>
```

and assuming you only want 'enter' do do something on the settings menu, use: `Template.settingsMenu.events`
Then, when `settingsMenu` is destroyed, so is the event handler.
If you bizarrely don't have one (ie the current route doesn't have a single unique template on it), create one:

```
<template name="settingsMenu">
</template>

{{>settingsMenu}}

Template.settingsMenu.events({...
```

Additionally, an ugly fix would be to add a conditional at the top of your event:
`if (Router.current().route.getName() === 'settingsMenu')...` I call this ugly because you still have a rogue event listener there, it's just harmless for all but your specified route.